# Where is the Update method in ServerManager?

Tags: c#, iis, servermanager

I am trying to create a WebSite in IIS Version 8 by following this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2006/04/17/microsoftwebadministration.aspx)

Added the reference to Microsoft.Web.Administration.

This line:

```
iisManager.Update();
```

gives this error:

> 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager' does not contain a
>   definition for 'Update' and no extension method 'Update' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of Update try CommitChanges()